# why does roc auc score give wrong score?

Tags: python, regression, logistic-regression, roc

I'm using logistic regression for a binary classification problem in Python. I chose ROC AUC score as evaluation metrics because i have class imbalance problem. I trained the data on train set and plot the ROC curve and calculated the ROC AUC score and got a score of 0.91 :

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()

logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)

y_pred_proba = logreg.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba,pos_label = 1)

roc_auc_score(y_test,y_pred_proba)
```

I was curios to see what score other threshold gives and in general how do thresholds and their ROC AUC score look. So I used the thresholds I got from the above code (`fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba,pos_label = 1)`) and calculate the ROC AUC for each of these thresholds:

```
scores = [roc_auc_score(y_test, logreg.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]>t) for t in thresholds]
results = pd.DataFrame({'threshold':thresholds,'ROC_AUC':scores})
```

The `results` dataframe would have two columns, thresholds and their corresponding ROC AUC score.
Surprisingly, the highest ROC AUC score I get is 0.85 and 0.91 doesn't even show up! This makes me wonder how the roc_auc_score calculates the score...

Can someone help me with this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please see "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" and include a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The ROC AUC has no dependence on the threshold, that's kind of it's point. The ROC curve itself is a parametric curve of the threshold but once you calculate the area under that curve you are basically integrating the dependence on threshold away. Said another way, the `roc_auc_score` function will handle everything to do with the threshold internally, so your `scores` list doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I read that there is a build in threshold in roc_auc_score whihc is 0.5 and that gave me the illusion that it is giving me the score at 0.5 threshold...